# I need to show only records that start with a prefix of "250" in my table from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, filter, html-table

Instead of displaying all of my records, I need to filter only the records that start with "250".  Is there a way to alter my existing table script to only show records that start with "250"?

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", "naturan8_hero");
$query = "SELECT type, part_no, description, artwork, min, max, qty FROM cartons_current     LIMIT 0,100"; 
$result = $db->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
$o = '<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"><thead><tr><th>TP&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Item Number&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th><th>Description</th><th>Artwork No.   </th><th class="hidden">PDF &nbsp; &nbsp;</th><th>Min &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Max &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Qty&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  </tr></thead><tbody>';
while(list($type, $part_no, $description, $artwork, $min, $max, $qty) = $result->fetch_row()) {
$o .= '<tr><td>'.$type.'</td><td class="ptn">'.$part_no.'</td><td>'.$description.'</td><td>'.$artwork.' &nbsp; &nbsp;</td><td class="hidden"><a href="/data/hero/upload/'.$part_no.'.pdf" target="_blank">Link &nbsp;</a></td><td align="right" class="min">'.$min.'</td><td align="right" class="max">'.$max.'</td><td align="right" class="quantity"> '.$qty.'</td></tr>';}
$o .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $o;
?>
```

Comment: oops. Sorry.  The $part_no column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
SELECT type, part_no, description, artwork, min, max, qty FROM cartons_current WHERE part_no like '250%'
```

or:

SELECT type, part_no, description, artwork, min, max, qty FROM cartons_current WHERE left(part_no,3) = '250'